# When sending 200 requests at once for REST we are getting pessimisticlock exception

Tags: java, rest, jboss, drools

We have a application build on Java using 
RESTful Webservice,
Server:JBoss EAP 7.0 ,For rules (Decision Table) :Java Business Process Model(JBPM) and we are using EJB.
Suppose for example while running sending a request for **1 user** we are getting output and everything works fine.
When we send **200 users** at once we are getting **pessimisticlock** exception and we are not able to get any output.
We are not using any database, we are just reading the values from decision table using drools.
So my question is:
When does PessimiticLock exception occur?
What can we do to handle multiple requests at once?
I have been searching on the net for pessmiticlockexception and i did not get much information.
So any help i get is appreciated.EDIT:
Mainly a error is caused in this line:

> FireAllRulesCommand fireAllRules = new FireAllRulesCommand();

And the decision tables are managed by JBPM and are stored in git repository.

Comment: You have not shown any code. How should we guess which part of it throws this exception?

Comment: *"not using any database ... reading from decision table"*. Where would that decision table be, if not in a database? Were is the pessimistic lock exception coming from, if not from a database? --- If you look at the full stacktrace of that exception, you'll see where the error is coming from. If you need help interpreting the stacktrace, then you need to add it to your question so we can see it.

Comment: @michalk due to privacy reasons i cannot post the code,  though i have edited the post and added the line where its all taking place. Andreas This is managed by the JBPM. This error is occured in different tables and everything is pointing at the line of code i have edited.